# Subversion dir in Git

Tags: git

In subversion I have this tree structure:

```
-->MyProject
   --> trunk
   --> branches
   --> tags
   --> documentation
```

I understand the meaning of the trunk, branches and tags in Git. But, in subversion, I have this dir "documentation", which contains some documents related to the project and are version independent. Is it possible to have such a dir in Git?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate git project for the documentation. If you put the directory inside another repo, make sure to exclude that directory from the outer project with .gitignore.

Comment: That seems devious. I'd rather keep the documentation inside the same repository. Maybe I'missing something obvious. Should I just create a directory "documentation" inside my project dir?

Comment: @BigJ: if you create a documentation directory in your project directory, you will either need to put it in .gitignore so that it's not versioned (or part of a separate repo as in my answer), or you will have to have it be versioned along with everything else. In SVN, the documentation directory is really acting like a separate project, so to match that with git, you'll need to create a separate repo. There's really no way around it.